# Is is possible to tell ocamlformat to ignore a specific portion of code

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, ocaml, ocamlformat

Is it possible to make `ocamlformat` ignore a specific portion of code by inserting some specific comments?

Here's what I tried, without success, using information found online:

```ml
(* @@disable *)
let some_unformatted_code = ...
(* @@enable *)

let formatted_code = ...
```

and

```ml
(* @@noformat *)
let some_unformatted_code = ...
(* @@format *)

let formatted_code = ...
```

without success. I'm programming in VSCode with the format on save option enabled.
This is my `.ocamlformat`:

```
profile = default
version = 0.26.0
parse-docstrings = true
```

am I doing something wrong? Is it possible that VSCode is not using ocamlformat but another generic formatter?

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ would you want to not have _part_ of your code not formatted automatically?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "ocamlformat.disable"?

Comment: @Chris there are plenty of reasons to do that. Sometimes, you are writing in a DSL the formatter does not know about. Sometimes, exceptionally, you judge that some code is more readable in a format that is not the one that the formatter would produce.

Comment: Exactly the second reason told by @jthulhu. I'm writing a chip8 emulator and I want to write the font matrix  by putting on each row the chars forming a font but instead of an nxm array, the formatter rearranges the array as a long column vector of size nmx1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[@@ocamlformat "disable"]` directive.

Example:

```ml
let positions_around (x, y) =
  [
    (x - 1, y - 1);  (x - 1, y);  (x - 1, y + 1);
    (x, y - 1);      (*(x, y);*)  (x, y + 1);
    (x + 1, y - 1);  (x + 1, y);  (x + 1, y + 1);
  ] [@@ocamlformat "disable"]
```